# How to deal with an employee who addresses the supervisor in an inappropiate tone?

Tags: management, leadership

I am having a difficult situation dealing with one particular employee right now. A very short background story is, he is a developer and I am the lead. On top of giving technical advises, I decide what tasks are allocated to the whole team and how much time they've got, I made the decision to hire them, & I advise the boss about their salary, who gets promoted etc.

One particular developer, let's call him John, seems to be not respecting my role. For example, the team repeatedly finish tasks without checking for mistakes. When I questioned who did it in kind of an angry tone, John jumped the conversion and responded "Yes, it was a mistake. But you should point that out in an email to us". (*Response in my head: when is it that you get to decide how I communicate to you?)*

On another occasion, I pulled one of our rarely used our servers offline. The team found that out during a demonstration session to a client. John messaged  me: "Next time, you should ask us before pulling it offline." (*Response in my head: oh, so YOU are telling me what to do now?*)

---

This is close to driving me nuts. I am still keeping temper right now, but I don't think I can hold it much longer if it happens again. The point is not who is at fault (please don't give an answer analyzing these two incidents about who did wrong or right). I am fairly open-minded to accept mistakes, and I do apologize to the whole team when I screwed up and caused everybody extra workload (happened once). It is the ***attitude***.

I don't want to lose temper in the whole office and shout him of his attitude, that would make me look really bad. Pulling him off to the side is slightly better, but if I accuse him our relationship is going to go sour. I am struggling to come up with alternatives.

If it makes any difference, this is his first job after graduation.

---

EDIT: question is now closed, but thanks everyone for pointing out that ***I myself is the problem***. I sincerely thank you for teaching me a valuable lesson on the internet. Your comments make me depressed, I'll admit; but negative criticisms are the best because they make you improve.

Comment: I think John is being reasonable - pulling out a server during a demo is not good. Perhaps listen to your team. They do have you interests at heart. Do you wish John to keep quite and ignore the cock ups

Comment: Put yourself in their shoes first. For the server example, it's likely they were actually thinking something much worse: (What were you thinking, taking the server down!? We totally embarassed ourselves in front of a client!!), but instead this was toned down to "Next time, you should ask us...".

Comment: @EdHeal the server is not off "during the demo". It was off for quite a while. They neglected to announce a demonstration session is coming(which is prearranged), and they neglected to check its status before the session begins.

Comment: I think your problem is that you think that you are separate from the team. You need to find a way off communicating with each other. The server is just an example. Why did you not ask if it was ok to switch it off with the rest of the team? Why do you have a preferred way of communicating what may not be best for other team members? Perhaps a little negotiation on that front. Phone works for some, email for others.

Comment: @kevin: It seems you are blaming everyone but yourself. Clearly you took off a server and neglected to enquire whether it was actually not used, and neglected to tell the team about it. I would be mightily pissed off with that kind of incompetence.

Comment: Suppose they had last checked that the server was ready for demo the day before, rather than some time earlier. That would not have solved the problem - you might have taken it offline that night. The best solution is to notify and consult all possible users of a server before taking it offline.

Comment: Anyway, Kevin is implying that the team needs to check every little thing all the time and cannot rely on anything. Or Kevin is one of those people who think people should read their mind, and when he turns off the server, they should know that and check whether the server is turned off, and if he didn't turn it off, then checking is obviously a waste of time.

Comment: "I decide what tasks are allocated to the whole team and how much time they've got," is the worst possible way of handling task assignment... the only people who can tell you how much time a task will take are the people doing it. and the most efficient way to assign tasks is by letting the people doing the work divide it amongst themselves. You sound like you have a very authoritive way of working, which usually doesn't go over well when working with programmers.

Comment: There are a few red flags here that tell me you are the problem, I'm afraid.    You seem to think that communicating with your team is beneath you and that they should be dogs who bark on command.  Maybe what you've written doesn't tell the whole story; but I'm afraid the situation you've described makes you sound like a terrible leader.

Comment: As a team lead, you should remove all obstacles in front of your team and shield them. It seems from your question that you are not only NOT doing that but that you are also creating new obstacles for them. Power and trust is not deserved, it has to be earned. If your whole team were to leave you'd find yourself quite powerless suddenly. Think about that.

Comment: I think John is expressing to you what the team do not talk to you but think about your actions

Comment: "thanks everyone for pointing out that I myself is the problem ... Your comments make me depressed, I'll admit; but negative criticisms are the best because they make you improve." You just gave yourself a fighting chance to become a good team leader :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What I'm hearing from your question here is that you think the role of a team lead is to decide how things should be done, and everyone on the team has to follow your One True Way of doing things. However, in the vast majority of workplace situations, that's not the case: the job of a team lead is to make their team better, and that involves finding the best way to communicate with each and every one of them.

In both the examples you've listed, it's clear that you didn't communicate with John on a way which he liked. It's as much on your shoulders to change your communication style as it is on John's to change his - otherwise you're likely making your team worse because you're not getting the best out of your staff. Try and work out a way to communicate with John that means everybody wins, not just you. Look in the mirror and think about how you could have done things better - for example, would it really have hurt anyone to let the team know you were taking the server down? Sure, they should have checked, but you could have told them as well. The aim is to make the demo go well, not to point a finger of blame at whoever did it wrong.

The above is what us English folk would call "direct" - full marks for accepting that you are at least part of the problem. However, I don't necessarily think that you're *all* of the problem - John's comments equally sound that they are not the best examples of office communication, and he could certainly do with improving his communication style as well. However, junior staff in their first job probably get more of a free pass than extant team leads - but if you can help John improve his communication style, then that's a good thing for a team lead to be doing.

Comment: John's attitude may have to do with the way he perceives the OP: I've seen many people acting like that (myself included) when the lead had no clue and made ridiculous unilateral decisions. There needs to be a culture of honesty and trust otherwise such feelings fester and the team ultimately collapses.

Comment: A big part of being professional is not acting like a prat even if the person you are talking is *is* acting like a prat.

Comment: Amen to that. In case it wasn't clear, I wasn't so much trying to say that John's comebacks were good/bad, but trying to explain what I think the root cause might be. If your team leads reacts the way the OP does everytime you want to complain about something, it is no surprise that things become passive-agressive (for a lack of a better alternative).

Answer (score 15):

> For example, the team repeatedly finish tasks without checking for mistakes. When I questioned who did it in kind of an angry tone, John jumped the conversion and responded "Yes, it was a mistake. But you should point that out in an email to us". (Response in my head: when is it that you get to decide how I communicate to you?)

I wouldn't object to using email. Email is in writing and all documentation of performance issues should be in writing. Verbal communication gets forgotten.

The response in your head is inappropriate. John is making a suggestion and you, as the team lead, need to evaluate the suggestion on its merit and not interpret it as an all-out attack on your authority. As team lead, you are first among equals not some petty dictator.

> On another occasion, I pulled one of our rarely used our servers offline. The team found that out during a demonstration session to a client. John messaged me: "Next time, you should ask us before pulling it offline." (Response in my head: oh, so YOU are telling me what to do now?)

You screwed it. You did not have enough respect for your team to warn them that you were hijacking a server. John is right. The fact that you are team lead does not entitle to act in a high handed manner and screw up what it is they are doing.

The response in your head is inappropriate. It's not about your ego and your sense of your prerogative. As a professional, John has the right to speak freely and point out that you shouldn't have done what you did. As a team lead, you are first among equals not some petty dictator.

> The point is not who is at fault (please don't give an answer analyzing these two incidents about who did wrong or right). I am fairly open-minded to accept mistakes, and I do apologize to the whole team when I screwed up and caused everybody extra workload (happened once). It is the **attitude**.

I agree, it's the attitude. Yours.

> I  don't want to lose temper in the whole office and shout him of his attitude, that would make me look really bad.

You have no idea how right you are. Right now, I am thinking that John not you should be team lead.

Summary:

You need to stop interpreting anything and everything John says as a direct attack on your authority and prerogatives as team lead. You need to evaluate what John says about any issue on the merits of what he says on how to deal with the issue and not in the context of your personal dislike for him. You are NOT dealing with the situation as-is. In fact, you are not dealing with the situation at all. You are failing as team lead.

I'll note that the most important quality I look for in any leader is humility. The humility to acknowledge and own one's mistakes and shortcomings. The humility to listen constructively to what the subordinates have to say. The humility to listen with an open mind to their suggestions because after all, we are all on the same side. The humility to want to work with the subordinates as individuals and as a team to get done what needs to get done. The humility to step up and take the blame on oneself if the team falls short.

I don't order my team around unless I have to pull rank. Instead, I work with my team. I take the attitude that I am my team and my team is me.

Comment: I'd agree with most of this, but I'm not seeing anything with says John has the skills to be a better team lead than the OP.

Comment: @PhilipKendall He's certainly better at root cause analysis!

Comment: Even if John was rude in his delivery and tone, that doesn't discredit what was being said. Likely, the other team members grumbled to themselves but didn't speak up. That's not good either.

Comment: @PhillipKendall - John has the guts to speak on behalf of the team and when speaks, he sticks to issues and to the specifics of the issues. Frankly, if I had a John on my team, I'd probably co-opt him as some sort of second-in-command - I could use a John who tells me like it is and keeps me grounded and honest :) I am a pretty strong team leader - I think. I have had strong subordinates and I am not afraid of having strong subordinates.

Comment: @VietnhiPhuvan True, I can even imagine John posting here, asking how to deal with a Team Lead named kevin :)

Comment: The team lead's job is to make it possible for the team to do their very best. OP did the opposite in the server case, and did not realise that in the first case, the email solution might be considered whether it also may have been better. Plus, being angry doesn't help. The most effective bosses are the ones that rarely get angry (but, where necessary, they always know that they can control their anger at the exactly right level).

Comment: "As team lead, you are first among equals not some petty dictator." Could not agree more.

Answer (score 1):

Just talk to him.

Tell him that how he manages upwards is as important a skill to have for career progression as managing his codebase, and managing his peers.

Ask him to be polite - I've had this done to me in the past (well, not for *this* but for other things) where my team lead would ask me to accompany him for lunch, buy me lunch, and talk to me about whatever it was I did.

I've found this works well - on one path, it is a free lunch, so that is a win. On another, it is a relaxed environment (lunch).

How you ask this is not about expressing your hurt feelings - it is advice on him on how to grow his career. If he's acting like this, he's probably lacking in manners and basic etiquette in all other aspects of life, mind, so you're going to need to be tactful, and blunt.

Discuss the issue - whatever it is that happened most recently - and then tell him you're putting your serious face on. Then tell him seriously that he needs to watch how he manages upwards, he needs to be respectful of senior managers, and then tell him how to be more respectful. In this case, it is not questioning the delivery of your management. Tell him if he has issues with it to bring them up with you privately.

I think that would sort it out for the most part.